# Passing arguments to a variadic function in C

Tags: c

I wrote this simple variadic function in C:

```
double averageVar(int cnt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, cnt);

    int i;
    double res = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        res += va_arg(args, double);
    }
    res /= cnt;
    va_end(args);

    return res;
}
```

When I use it like this:

```
averageVar(2, 4.0, 7.88);
```

It works fine, but calling it in this way:

```
averageVar(2, 4, 7.88);
```

yields some gibberish, namely: -0.000000. It seems like I have to pass integer values followed by .0. Why is that?

Comment: What is `4`?  Can that type be processed with `va_arg(args, double)`?

Comment: You are essentially asking why `printf("%lf", 4)` doesn't work.

Comment: Your function expects `double` parameters. You must provide parameters that match that type after common type promotion. Providing an integer is cheating your own function.

Comment: `averageVar(2, 4.0, 7.88);` or `averageVar(2, (double)4, 7.88);` works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`averageVar(2, 4, 7.88);` the second parameter is `int` not `double`. You need to pass the correct type parameter or cast

```
double averageVar(int cnt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, cnt);

    int i;
    double res = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        res += va_arg(args, double);
    }
    res /= cnt;
    va_end(args);

    return res;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", averageVar(2, 4.0, 7.88));
    printf("%f\n", averageVar(2, (double)4, 7.88));

    printf("%f\n", averageVar(2, 4, 7.88)); //wrong parameter type
}
```

generally constant values:

`4`     - integer type

`4.0f`  - float type

`4.0`   - double type

Comment: `4.0f` will be promoted to `double` anyway due to the default argument promotions

Comment: @M.M Indeed - just wanted to show numeric constants formats